# boost::asio::deadline_timer not expiring after async_read() and async_write() is done in timer handler

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have an async_connected() client, single threaded, and my `deadline_timer` is persisted as a member of some connection class.  My `deadline_timer` only goes off once and I'm trying to do 3 things when my deadline_timer expires:

1. async_write on socket1
2. async_read on socket1
3. async_wait on this same timer as I want this timer to go off again in 4 seconds.

The send and read work, the problem is the timer never expires again.  `io_service.run()` didn't not stop as the line right after it is not printed...  Why is my `deadline_timer` not expiring again?

Comment: Please post your code rather than words describing your code.

Comment: You will need to change the expiration time of the timer and call `async_wait()` again from your handler.

Comment: If you're learning from boost site then you'll give up sun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong, not sure why it resulted in the symptoms that I saw, but when I read with `async_read()` in the `deadline_timer` handler, after I was done I cleared out my `boost::asio::buffer` receive buffer with `memset()` after every read.  I know I probably do not need this memory cleanup.  The problem was that I was clearing more memory than I gave `async_read()` with the receive buffer, so I was memsetting invalid locations.  I am not sure why that resulted in the `deadline_timer` never firing again and also `async_read()` didn't work again after that either.